# Image goes beyond site border

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm learning how to make a website and I've finished my first page but for some reason I always see a white space on the side of the site, with a scroll bar to scroll to it. When I tried checking the site on a smaller screen, I noticed that my image goes beyond the border, so that's probably the issue. It shows up like this:[image]

with that code being the only place where I've included the image, the code is:

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <img  src="Images/home.png" class="img-flui">
</div>
```

and this is what the page looks like in full mode:
[image]
no idea what the issue is.
I've attempted to change the size of image and I've also tried to check if there is some other image whose size is bigger than it should be but I don't see anything, the full code is 200lines long not sure if i should share it

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: `class="img-flui"` seems to be a typo, have you tried `class="img-fluid"` on that image?

Comment: @brombeer yes i've tried it but it only makes the image disappear from the side and makes it normal,but i still see the white gap

Comment: @NicoHaase thats the only code involved in that picture/banner, should i share whole code of site? because thats the only part where i see the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to mess with css just set the image width to "80%" instead of fixed value. this will make the image with depend directly on its container width. You may also be interested in object-fit css property
More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will help anyone in the future but I had a typo in`"<div class="container">`, I typed contianer instead, I corrected it and the side space disappeared.